# Suggest tag merge: [android-exoplayer] to [exoplayer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Both of these tags refer to the same software, which is only available on the Android platform so the more specific tag name is redundant.  Almost all questions in [android-exoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-exoplayer) are already tagged [exoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exoplayer) as well, and that is by far the more popular tag.

Answer (score 1):

This has now been implemented.

As you say, Exoplayer is only available on the Android platform, so the prefix wart is unnecessary.

**[exoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exoplayer)** has been made the master tag. [android-exoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-exoplayer) was merged into that, and a synonym mapping was created.

There is also a version-specific [exoplayer2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exoplayer2.x) tag, which is now easier to find.